# how to stop response for each input event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to perform the search dropdown item add into the table. 
*problem statement* -- 
After first search when i am pressing the backspace request call for each input event and response come according to that, so is it possible after search and press backspace then response will not come for each and every input?.

---

Comment: Is there any solution for this?

Comment: So that I understand your question. You want to limit how often the search function executes and not on every keyUP or keyDown?

Comment: You can prevent it from occuring on backspace, prevent it from occuring more than n times per second, prevent it from occuring if the user hasn't stopped typing yet, there's several ways of throttling user input to achieve a more responsive UI. Which one are you looking for?

Comment: Does this help you? 
https://dev.to/przemwo/how-to-execute-a-function-only-after-the-user-stops-typing-beh

Comment: @DallasBaker yes, thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so what you want to do is is set a timeout, this way the onChange function won't execute until after X amount of time from the last change.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => console.log(`I can see you're not typing. I can use "${value}" now!`), 1000);
    return () => clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  }, [value]);

  return(
    <>
      <h1>{value}</h1>
      <input onChange={handleOnChange} value={value} />
    </>
  );
};
```